# Regarding the study of algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

Eventually, I want to be able to study algebraic geometry. My question is relatively straightforward: will studying polynomials and doing competition level problems related to polynomials right now be helpful (as "preparation" so to speak)?

Comment: I think not. Even classical algebraic geometry was about _structure_, not so much "tricks". Sure, it's hard for a novice to distinguish the two, which makes it all the worse... but, over time, people _did_ distinguish "lasting tricks", which became "methods/ideas", as opposed to more-isolated, contest-style tricks. Probably abstract algebra is the next part of a route to algebraic geometry.

Comment: @paulgarrett As much as that is true, it doesn't hurt to be intimately familiar with the way that polynomials work mechanically. But I agree that the best place to start is by learning some abstract algebra.

Comment: Much better to study some projective geometry.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, indeed, up to a point classical algebraic geometry was to some degree "synthetic", and was an extension (in terms of sensibilities and goals) of classical projective geometry.

Comment: What about learning linear algebra first...?

Comment: EGA is self contained....hahaha.

Comment: Maybe you should say a little bit more about your background. What makes you want to learn algebraic geometry? What do you already know? Algebraic geometry as modern research mathematicians understand it involves a huge amount of different things (and has a huge number of very different flavoured sub-areas), so it's hard (and maybe undesirable) to give a singular and concise answer.

Comment: @Remy Well...I'm just a high school student! Of course, I know there is a LOT of other stuff I need to know, but these other prerequisites have already been thoroughly discussed in other questions on this site. So that's why, since I know the field studies zeroes of polynomial equations, I thought I would ask a question pertaining specifically to polynomials.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I think you'll find that some of the competition-level problems on polynomials are similar to things that you'll find later in abstract algebra books, except that the latter provide better context and motivation for some questions, and tend to focus on things that are relevant in higher math. I don't think it can hurt to do these kinds of problems (e.g. in Lidsky and Krechmar's problem books). However, if you're sufficiently motivated, you can also (or instead) start studying algebra in a book like Artin's. Oh, for your previous question: $f(x) = \sqrt{x} \sin(1/x)$.